# Break for C compilation

Tags: c, compilation

I am new to C. I encountered an error message which involves unexpected "}". However, I checked the number of "}" with an editor and indeed they pair up.

Then I wonder if there is a compiler command, so the compilation can stop whatever I want? It will be convenient to have such tool as debug help.

Thank you.

(Edited in 29-10-2015)
I typically write my code with gedit. Nonetheless, since my work is mostly done on cluster, it will be troublesome to transport the files up and down. I must turn to nano, vi or vim which causes difficulty in debugging.

Comment: Use a good IDE. They usually pick up such things before compiling

Comment: use a static check tool like this one http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Perhaps you miss a semicolon `;` before the `}`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Another possibility is a missed `"` enclosing a string literal.

Comment: What I would like to know is a general method to approach debugging. It is not just this error which is likely be solved with an editor. That's why I did not include the code itself.

Comment: We cannot read your mind, so anything we can say is only a guess.  Do you want a real answer to the error message, then post the code.  IF you want to know how to debug, this is not the place to find out.

Comment: the compiler `gedit` is rather 'iffy' for development.  Suggest install `geany` (a free download).   `geany` contains a compiler, linker, and one click running of the code and a lot of other features that `gedit` does not have, features that are very useful for editing, compiling, debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stopping compilation partway through is rarely a useful feature.  You'll want to see all of the errors that may exist in your code so you can fix more that just one at a time.

That said, an error such as a misplaced brace or parenthesis can cascade down and cause several more errors to appear.  So if you see a long list of errors that don't seem to make sense when you look at the code, start at the top and fix that, then recompile to see if it took care of any others.

Comment: Indeed stopping compilation might actually produce even more trouble. What I normally do is to do it with a better editor, then printf to see if it makes sense.
However, most of my work is done on cluster. Only vim, vi and nano are supported as far as I can tell.

Comment: communication with a cluster will make even the best editor seem like it is full of cold molasses.  Suggest download the code to be edited to a local file, edit/compile locally, when correct, then upload the new version.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no compilers are all or nothing.

However, a good editor is recommended.  For example, you can match brackets with the % command in vi, or if you have a color editor, you can visually see what's going on.  A better IDE would even allow you to hide/show blocks of code, format it with proper indentation, and flag any compilation issues from static rules without actually compiling your code.